# The word "Jaggernaut" originated from an Indian word

Tags: etymology

What is it ? Does anyone know the real meaning ?

Comment: Advice: do a little googling for yourself, this information is easy to find. One learns a great deal by researching ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Juggernaut

This is from Sanskrit jagat "the world, men and beasts" (literally "the moving, all that moves," present participle of *jagati "he goes," from PIE *gwa- "to go, come" (see come (v.)) + natha-s "lord, master," from nathate "he helps, protects," from PIE root *nā- "to help." The first European description of the festival is by Friar Odoric (c. 1321).

See the [online etymology dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=juggernaut&allowed_in_frame=0)

The word is used in English to indicate a powerful, overwhelming force, and is sometimes used to describe large, articulated lorries, especially when they pass through small towns and villages on narrow roads.

> The size of these Juggernauts these days!